# Uninstallation of Vista gadget

Tags: windows-vista, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have developed a test vista gadget. Zipped it and renamed it to ".gadget". Its a valid installer for the gadget & it works well.

Is there any standard way to un-install the same gadget? What I am looking for is programmatic way to un-install the gadget.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the + sign at the top of the sidebar.
2. Right-click the gadget you want to uninstall in the list of gadgets.
3. Select Uninstall.